# How to hide bottomsheet when keyborad is up

Tags: flutter, google-maps, stack, flutter-positioned

[i Want to fix the bottomsheet down when keyboard comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbbo0.png)

[Here is the code strcuture how i created the stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvGVt.png)

Comment: Hello, please refrain from posting screenshots of your code. It is better that you directly put it here so that the community could reproduce it and help you with your issue. Since you're new, here's a guide in [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) questions here and also a guide for posting [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that could help you in your next questions here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `FocuseNode` in your `Textfield`

something like this:

```
    FocusNode focusNode;

void initState() {
  focusNode = new FocusNode();

  // listen to focus changes
  focusNode.addListener(() => print('focusNode updated: hasFocus: ${focusNode.hasFocus}')); 
}

void setFocus() {
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
}

Widget build() {
  return
  ...
  new TextField(focusNode: focusNode, ...);
}
```